# Definition of Galois category.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and my definition of étale $K$-algebra is $K$-algebra $L$ which is isomorphic to a finite product of finite separable field extensions of $K$.

I found

> Let $G$ denote the absolute Galois group of $K$. Then the category of étale $K$-algebras is equivalent to the category of finite $G$-sets with continuous $G$-action.

in properties section of [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_algebra#Properties), and want to show this by checking that it satisfies the definition of the Galois category by Grothendieck.

First of all, I searched reference of galois category and there are two different definition.
The one that does not use strict epimorphism is in [this pdf](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf), and the second is use strict epimorphism is in [this pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eanna.cadoret/FG.pdf).

I have two questions.

1. Which is good for beginner of galois theory?
   Or they are equivalent?
2. What are morphisms of the category of étale $K$-algebras? Are they $K$-algebra morphisms?

Comment: Given that Wikipedia can be edited, you might want to give more context in your question. What is $K?$ What is the base field?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for your advice. I added context.